# Mongo Shell update nested array of documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell, nested-documents

I try to set an attribute of an document inside an array to uppercase.
Here is the link to the mongodb playground https://mongoplayground.net/p/BTP_h3kqK_S

this is a document example

```
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e786a078bc3b3333627341e"),
    "value": {
      "items": [
        {
          "itemName": "alpha305102992",
          "itemNumber": ""
        },
        {
          "itemName": "beta305102630",
          "itemNumber": "P5000"
        },
        {
          "itemName": "gamma305102633 ",
          "itemNumber": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I try to set the "itemName" to upper case.

My desired result would be:

```
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e786a078bc3b3333627341e"),
    "value": {
      "items": [
        {
          "itemName": "ALPHA305102992",
          "itemNumber": ""
        },
        {
          "itemName": "BETA305102630",
          "itemNumber": "P5000"
        },
        {
          "itemName": "GAMMA305102633 ",
          "itemNumber": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: It works at the playground.
But my Robo 3T says "Request is malformed".
Any Ideas, what i did wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$map` to iterate loop of `value.items` array
- convert `itemName` to upper case using `$toUpper`
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object with updated `itemName` field

```
db.collection.update({},
  [{
    $set: {
      "value.items": {
        $map: {
          input: "$value.items",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              { itemName: { $toUpper: "$$this.itemName" } }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tic0ciPBuFQ)

Answer (score 0):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/geb1MRHXNyk

Use [update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      value: {
        items: { // set item to loop only once
          $map: {
            input: "$value.items", // loop over items
            in: {
              $mergeObjects: [ // merge document
                "$$this",
                { itemName: { $toUpper: "$$this.itemName" } } // change individual itemName to upper
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

---

aggregation demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/9wtSkyjC88c

Demo with your playgroud link - https://mongoplayground.net/p/5J7Qz97gZoJ

update demo with playground link - https://mongoplayground.net/p/8LHEuMakpFF